# Each time I refresh the webpage, the first row added is being duplicated

Tags: php, header, duplicates

I'm creating a small comment system, which displays all comments above each other. Problem is that each time I press the submit button the first row added in the database is duplicated. Which results in displaying alot of the same comments. I already try using header and exit, but that didn't worked out either. Could it be maybe have to do with the form action? Thanks in advance.

```
public function comment($username, $comment)
{
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($comment)) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if ($insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (username, comment, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert->bind_param('sss', $username, $comment, $date);
            $insert->execute();
        } else {
            echo "something is wrong with the query";
        }
    } else {
        echo "missing fields";
    }
}
```

Here is the usage, The form is echo'd below this, as you can see, I redirect to avoid duplication and then exit

```
$reizen = new reizen;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $comment  = $_POST['comment'];
    header("Location: index.php?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $reizen->comment($username, $comment);
    exit();
}
echo $reizen->retrieve();
```

Comment: You need to swap rows
`header("Location: index.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`
And
`$reizen->comment($username, $comment);`

Comment: Thanks, but it still duplicates, more ideas?

Comment: If it always happens, your comment function gets called twice somehow or your db has a funky trigger that duplicates rows :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) to prevent this.